# Spring data jpa repository property not found

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring Data JPA. I've tried to create a custom method for the repository but it does throw an exception. Here is my current implementation:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends
CrudRepository<Employee, Long>,EmployeeRepositoryCustom {

}

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepositoryCustom {

    public void updateEmployee(String field, String value,long id);
}

public class EmployeeRepositoryImpl implements EmployeeRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext 
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void updateEmployee(String field, String value, long id) {
        // Implementation goes here
    }

}
```

And this is the exception that occurs when I start the application (I am using Spring boot).

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property updateEmployee found for type Employee!
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
```

Comment: From the docs: `If you use namespace configuration, the repository infrastructure tries to autodetect custom implementations by scanning for classes below the package we found a repository in.` is the implementation in a subpackage of the repo?

Comment: implementation also in the same package

Comment: That should work as is. Care to share a sample project that shows the error?

Comment: Your code is fine.  Copying it to a fresh Spring Boot project [works](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-jpa-custom).  Something else in your application is causing problems.  Are you trying to supply a custom implementation for all repositories?  I have encountered this error when attempting to provide a custom implementation for all repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged `spring-boot`, I assume you are using spring-boot. If so, you can try following method.

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepositoryCustom {

@Modifying
@Query(value = "update Employee query", nativeQuery = true)
public void updateEmployee(String field, String value,long id);

}
```

You do not need to have an implementation and you can have named parameters in query above. `Spring-boot` will handle rest.